# Which is the best for Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Which is the best for Microsoft SQL Server 2008? I would like to have information on PIVOT, Triggers, Stored Procedures, CLR integration, Service Broker etc all in one book.

Answer (score 3):

Read SQL Books on line.

Answer (score 0):

Books are a very personal choice. So its hard to recommend 1. But i find the publishers wrox and o'reilly do an excellent range of books on SQL and other topics.